# Play Framework 2.0 correct way to represent a set in a query using Anorm

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I am trying to return a list of results using Anorm using a query that returns matching rows for a set of ids. Eg.

```
select *
from example
where id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

If I try

```
SQL(
    """
      select *
      from example 
      where id in ({ids})
    """
  ).on('ids -> ids).as(int("id") ~ str("name") *)
```

where ids is the String "1,2,3,4,5" it will only return the first row. What is the correct way to inject the set of ids?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no simple way of doing it AFAIK.

This is how I solved it:

```
def findSomething(ids: String) = {
  // Split up the comma separated values
  val sids = ids split ","
  // Create a list of keys (id0, id1, id2, ...)
  val keys = for ( i <- 0 until sids.size ) yield ("id" + i)
  // Create a seq of parameterized values
  val values = sids map (toParameterValue(_))

  // Now zip together the keys and values into list of tuples
  val params = keys zip values

  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL(
      """
        select *
        from example 
        where id in ({%s})
      """.format(keys.mkString("},{"))
    ).on(
      params: _*
    ).as(
      int("id") ~ str("name") *
    )
  }
}
```

**NB**
The cruical part here is the string formatting in the SQL statement. It is vulnerable for SQL injection if you don't have total control of your input parameters.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the info, it felt like I was doing it the wrong way anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but this is still a bit crazy and anorm needs to have support for parameterized sequences. Not to mention the fact that using the "scala noob expected-to-work" binding technique with strings produces perfectly valid SQL in the logger but silently fails.

Comment: @notbrain It has been discussed plenty of times in the Play dev team, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/meYkd-KKQRE), [here](http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/188-make-in-clause-in-anorm-easier) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/BNFvma2vu5U) for starters. But I totally agree with you that this should be fixed. My answer here is just one way to get around the shortcomings of anorm and `IN` clauses.

Comment: Thanks for the links; my bad habit is when I see that they are over a year old I tend to overlook them :). Also 2.1 vs 2.0 confusion. Not sure why the IN() clause and auto parameterizing Sequences is considered such an odd request.